# Что необходимо сделать для "привязки" события к функции-обработчику этого события

Tags: c#

Разбираюсь в программировании недавно, появился такой вопрос:
"Что необходимо сделать для "привязки" события к функции-обработчику
этого события?"
В инете толком ничего не нашёл, поэтому решил написать сюда.

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под "привязкой события к функции-обработчику"?

Comment: _"Что необходимо сделать для "привязки" события к функции-обработчику этого события?"_ - подписаться на него. То есть этот вопрос правильно звучит "Как подписаться на событие?", вот и ищите по этим ключевым словам. Паттерн Publisher/Subscriber читайте, изучайте.

Answer (score 2):

"Наивная" версия ответа на Ваш вопрос - "Для привязки события к функции-обработчику нужно событию назначить функцию-обработчик"

Синтаксис такого назначения - это "то самое"

`Событие += Обработчик события`

Например, в случае форм

`Shown += OnFormShown`

Здесь `Shown` - событие, `OnFormShown()` - функцию-обработчик

А наивность ответа заключается в отсутствии теории про делегаты.

И я хочу Вас поправить - информации на эту тему-сколько угодно!

Comment: Вся теория делегатов - это _"переменная или член класса, который в качестве значения содержит в себе ссылку на один или несколько методов"_ :) Меня на самом деле удивляет, когда преподаватели по шарпу начинают выделять делегаты как что-то отдельное и сложное. Оно совсем не отдельное и совсем не сложное.